# Grub not loading for dual boot set-up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bios

I am trying to install dual boot on a PC - windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed windows first and then in the BIOS through a USB installed Ubuntu.

I made the following partitions:

SSD Hard disk-

- sda1: fat 32 273MB mounted /boot/efi
- sda3: windows NTFS 60GB
- sda4: NTFS 472MB
- sda5: BIOS boot 1MB
- sda6 linux swap
- sda7 linux filesystem ext4 50GB mounted file root system

Secondary Disk-

- sdb1 - microsoft reserved 134MB
- sdb2 -linux filesystem ext2 (v1) not mounted 16GB
- sdb3: linux swap (v1) active 16GB

When I start the computer, it bypasses GRUB and goes straight to windows. I can access ubuntu in legacy mode through the BIOS, but I cannot select it on start up.

In the BIOS the boot menu contains the following:

- UEF: IP4 realtek PCI & GBE family controller
- SATA6G_1: samsung ssd 850 EVO2 (238475MB)
- SATA6G_2: WDC WD10EZEX-21 WN4A0 (953869MB)
- Windows boot manager (SATA6G_1: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB)

I can load linux through SATA6G_1: samsung ssd 850 EVO2 (238475MB).

BootInfo summary:

http://paste2.org/BeWbOaee

Comment: On my laptop I am able to choose the bootloader to start on boot. Are you able to change it in bios?

Comment: where can I find settings for grub in the bios?

Comment: You have an UEFI system with Windows installed in UEFI boot mode. But you installed Ubuntu in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. You can UEFI boot into Ubuntu installer/Boot-Repair from UEFI (not BIOS) and in advance mode run the full uninstall/reinstall of grub. That will convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot mode.https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  It also looks like you left Windows fast start up or hibernation on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred  I ran boot repair and that seemed to fix the problem. thanks for your help and suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

---

Fix...

I did a scan and repair using boot repair and it seems to have worked, as GRUB loads on start up and I can choose Ubuntu. Although it did say that there was an error during repair.

Results of repair below:

http://paste2.org/d32y7jPP